# What to use when referring to the character 格

Tags: mandarin

In Chinese, you can use 博士的博 to indicate the character 博 instead of other bó. Like a for apple or b for baby.

What about for the character 格, what do most Chinese people commonly use in practice to indicate / address the character 格 instead of other characters that represents the same sound gé?

Note I'm asking in the context of when someone is trying to spell a word to another person that is writing what he listening to. And that word coincidentally contains the character 博. Using what word would you address it since the characater 博 doesn't have an official name of its own in chinese.

Regards,

Comment: submit 格 to 小马词典 to find 66 words starting with 格 and 285 words containing 格, e.g. may say 价格 的 格

Comment: below find frequency numbers of suggested words: 价格  （價格）#792,風格 ＃２４８５, 品格 #9434，人格 #3249，,規格＃７５８３,体格，（體格） #19711，for 严格，資格 frequency # n.a., among these  价格  （價格） has highest frequency

Comment: Soryy newbie how did you dislplay the frequency? I mean how did you sort the frequency?

Comment: frequency ## copied from bkrs,

Comment: what is bkrs? Sorry I'm new to this. I'm using http://www.xiaoma.info. Are you using this site too?

Comment: Chinese-Russian-English dictionary, https://bkrs.info/

Comment: why do you say 792 as the highest? isn't 2485 higher frequency than 792? What does the number even mean? Sorry newbie

Comment: numbers quoted in above comments are the **frequency rank** , readers of Chinese would be fairly certain that 价格 is more common than any of the others mentioned above, see  e.g.   List of Chinese characters ordered by frequency rank (from most common to least common) http://hanzidb.org/character-list/by-frequency

Comment: information about bkrs's word frequency ranks seems elusive, 
frequency rank for characters is better known and more readily available,
for short list of frequency rank of words see 现代汉语常用词表 http://www.moe.gov.cn/ewebeditor/uploadfile/2015/01/13/20150113085920115.pdf

Comment: bkrs's basis for its word frequency ranks: База - взяты две, официальная из СМИ и более разговорная (за основу) обе по ~50 000 слов и объеденины - слов которых нет в разговорной влиты. https://bkrs.info/taolun/thread-86393.html

Comment: Just to confirm, this ranking system involves not only words containing 格but for all words in chinese, Correct me if I'm wrong..?

Comment: Also Is there any other method of knowing whether a word is common or not in usage other than using this particular ranking system and without having to ask a chinese person to confirm it? Is the number of results in google search reliable enough for a word to be called common?

Comment: users suggest web search with e.g. "usage frequency tables of Chinese words" 汉语词利用频度表, one hit: 汉语词汇统计研究 http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/tli/guideline/changyongzibiao.pdf

Comment: So this ranking is ranking all the words in chinese and not just those containing 格, Am I wrong?

Comment: "all words" is evidently impossible, see Modern Chinese Character Frequency List 现代汉语单字频率列表 Jun Da 笪骏 (jda@mtsu.edu) which seems more or less universally accepted, for word frequency lists see Table 1 Word frequency lists of Chinese. in   ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2880003

Comment: Please don't delete your comments. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordsearch.php

Search 格 by Chinese word. You will find many compound words with 格

The following are the most common ones

> 風格, 品格, 人格, 嚴格, 資格, 價格, 規格, 體格

You can say 風格的格, 品格的格 ... and so on

You can also use terms like 格局, 格鬥, 格調, 格式. To clarify which character you meant to say, the examples you used just need to contain 格, it doesn't matter where it is in a compound word

To make it extra clear, you can even use four characters idioms like

'格' as in "[格格不入](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/48648/)"

'格' as in "[別具一格](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/48648/)"

Comment: I don't understand, your examples non start with 格 only ends with it. Don't you use a word or vocab that starts with 格 instead of one that ends with 格 to indicates the character 格? as in a in apple, b in baby..etc. Sorry i'm noobi

Comment: Soory again what is 的格? Lattice? what does that mean?

Comment: why do you understand  博士的博 (博 as in 博士) but not understand 風格的格 (格 as in 風格)?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand Chinese very well as much as you do. I did understand 博士的博 because in google translate it is translated as "Dr's bo". But 風格的格 it is translated as just "style". And 風格 is also translated as "style" while 的格 is translated as "lattice". That's why I asked what is lattice here mean? Am I missing something or was there something that was...lost in translation?

Comment: Also doesn't chinese people use words that "starts" with the character that he intends to address when spelling something instead of choosing a word that "ends" with it ? like in a for apple, b for baby. It's far more intuitive and easier to notice this way, don't you think? Your example 風格 ends with 格, it doesn't start with 格. Is it really usually like this or is it just me that is getting the impression that chinese people likes to make things more errr.... how do you say this.... complicated?

Comment: I didn't get why you say " it doesn't matter where it is (located) in a compound word". To make things clear, It is very veerrryy.... unusual in english to spell the letter "a" using the word "extra" for example. As in:  a for "extra", b for "knob", etc.. compare that with : a for "apple, b for "baby" when trying to spell a word to somebody in english....You get my point, right? Is it just me or is there a very big difference in mindset here between chinese vs english speaking people? Because In english, where the referred character is (located),...IT MATTERS. It HAS to be at the beginning.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 It doesn't matter where it is in the word in Chinese (because it's a morpheme not a single letter). Here are comparable examples in English: "-ology, like in geology or biology", "the -phile in sinophile, not the file in nail file".

Comment: Thank you for the clear clarification. I also wanted to confirm what the 的 in 風格的格 meant? Does it mean like the possesive ['s] in english so that it actually translates to "style's gé" ? am I  wrong in assuming this?